# does openfire interfere with mysql or phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, openfire

I have installed php, mysql, phpmyadmin on windows server 2008 and everything is working fine. Now, I installed Openfire and i connected it to mysql database. the problem that i am having now is when every i run openfire i can't connect to database or login phpmyadmin. It seems like openfire is interfering with mysql ports! I am using port 3306 for mysql. I belive openfire is using 9090 and 9191.

so when I have open fireopen my php scripts will not be able to connect to the database and also i won't be able to log in to phpmyadmin. But when i close openfire then everything works fine again.

Can any one help me with betting both to work next to each other eith no issue please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. the problem was that a min connection in openfire was set to 100 and Mysql max connection was also set to 100. So I have increased the max connection allowed and that fixed the issue.